# How to print a string on pdf header in yii2

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I am working on `yii2` framework. I am printing a `pdf` file using `kartik\mpdf\Pdf`. There is a field named `subdivision` which I want to print on the header of the `pdf` file.

```
$sql_r = "SELECT DISTINCT ogph.`id` AS 'OGP_Serial_No',DATE(ogph.`created_at`) AS 'Date',uu.`name` AS 'Created_By',ogpd.`meter_serial` AS 'Meter_Serial_Number',  u.`name` AS 'Issued_To', ps.`name` AS 'Store',sd.`name` AS 'Sub_Division',
IFNULL(ogph.`admin_incharge`,'') AS 'Admin_Incharge', IFNULL(ogph.`project_manager`,'') AS 'Project_Manager', IFNULL(ogph.`driver_name`,'') AS 'Driver_Name', IFNULL(ogpd.`remarks`,'') AS 'Remarks'  
FROM `ogp_header` ogph
INNER JOIN `ogp_detail` ogpd ON ogph.`id` = ogpd.`ogp_id` 
INNER JOIN `user` u ON ogph.`issuer` = u.`id`  
INNER JOIN `user` uu ON ogph.`created_by` = uu.`id`
INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON ogph.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code`
INNER JOIN `project_store` ps ON ogph.`store_id` = ps.`id` $where AND ogph.`id` = $ogp_id";
        $sql_r = $sql_r . " LIMIT " . $from . " OFFSET " . $to;

        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $sql_r,
            'pagination' => false
        ]);


    $content = $this->renderPartial('view_pdf_ogp', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);

    $pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use core fonts only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
        // A4 papr format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        // stream to browser inline
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
        // your html content input
        'content' => $content,
        // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
        // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:14px}',
        // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => ['title' => 'OGP Document'],
        // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader' => ['Name.||Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")],
            'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}']
        ]
    ]);
```

In above code, I want to do something like `'SetHeader' => ['Accurate (PVT) LTD.|Sub-Division: Here I want to print the sub division name|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")],`

**What I have tried?**

I have tried to do it by adding

`'SetHeader' => ['Name.|Sub-Division: '.<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['Sub_Division'])?>.'|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")]`

and also

```
'SetHeader' => ['Name.|Sub-Division: '.$content->Sub_Division.'|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")],
```

But Both are giving me `non-object` error. Is there any method to put a string on the header taken from a query ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is related to the PDF class? Can you generate the string to be written to the header without problems or is the string you generated not saved properly in the PDF file?

Comment: `$content` is a string containing your rendered viewed. so this `$content->Sub_Division` will always throw the non-object error.

Comment: Why not use a custom function to get the Sub_division then append it to your header?

Comment: **USTAD** ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ what are you doing here?  `['Accurate (PVT) LTD.|Sub-Division: '.<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['Sub_Division'])?>.'|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'SetHeader' => ['Accurate (PVT) LTD.|Sub-Division: '.<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['Sub_Division'])?>.'|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")]
```

What are you trying to achieve with above lines of code, You are setting an array index `SetHeader` which expects its value to be a string, why php tags and why `print_r` when you just have to concatenate multiple strings. Read it like below.

```
'SetHeader' => ['header string goes here']
```

That being said, you can set header by two methods.

**Method 1**

Supply header in configuration array (thats the method you are trying), but you are not building header string in a correct way. It should be like following.

```
'SetHeader' => ['Accurate (PVT) LTD.|Sub-Division: '.$dataProvider->getModels()[0]['Sub_Division'].'|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")]
```

Above configuration means "Call `SetHeader` method of `mPDF` class with supplied argument".

**Method 2**

Alternatively, you can obtain `mPDF` object and call its `SetHeader` method directly.

```
$mpdf = $pdf->api; // fetches mpdf api
$mpdf->SetHeader('Accurate (PVT) LTD.|Sub-Division: '.$dataProvider->getModels()[0]['Sub_Division'].'|Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"));
```